# SDL2 in Android library

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, sdl-2

I'm currently trying to add SDL2 library in a Android library.

Android project is managed only with a CMakeList.txt file (no Android.mk)

I'm not able to make it compile. It's a basic C++ android gradle project,
in the CMakeList.txt I added the line:

```
add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/AAA/third_party/SDL2")
```

But I'm getting linker error like

```
fatal error: 'SDL2/SDL.h' file not found
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Someone can explain me how can I add SDL2 to an existing CMakelist.txt for an android project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the includes in the CMakeLists.txt as well

```
# per target include
target_include_directories(your_target public "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/AAA/third_party/")
```

```
# globally
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/AAA/third_party/")
```

pd: I omitted the SDL2 in the path since you seem to include the headers as `<SDL2/XXX.h>` if you want to include the headers directly `<XXX.h>` add SDL2 to the paths ie:

```
target_include_directories(your_target public "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/AAA/third_party/SDL2")
```